# Does 6 cores ryzen 5 3600 x or 8 cores ryzen 7 3800x or intel i7 6700k or ryzen 9 3950x used for website/Nas enterprise based server

Tags: network-attached-storage, cpu-usage, website

I was thinking to set up a server for my tracking system or inventory management system. and I would like to know is 6 cores or 4 cores enough for the bare minimum or should i get 8 cores or the 16 cores cpu because I don't want to buy some overkill server that just do relatively simple task?

What do you guys think?

```
Here is what i'll be doing for my server:
-NAS
-Website Hosting
-Inventory and Tracking System. 

I'm also planning to set RAID Array for it too here is the 2 i'm considering:
- Raid 1+0
- Raid 6+1
- Raid 1 
- Raid 6+1+0

And yes is there any recommendations for raid controller.

I would also need to consider the ram and mother:
For Ram (ECC) :
- 8gb
- 16gb
- 32gb
- 64gb


Motherboard:
- refurbished desktop ( i7 6th gen)
- MSI Z170A (ATX)
- X570M (mini ITX)
- X570 (ATX)
- B540M
```

Comment: Product and service recommendations are not allowed on Server Fault. https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Well that was not recommending product and services

Comment: i was just asking about CPU cores and RAID

Comment: The RAM and MOTHERBOARD is only specifying what sort of things i might buy to determine what they might recommend on the software side of things and cores

Comment: There is no way to recommend anything without knowing your uses, traffic, and so on. Everything would just be a wild guess.

Comment: I'm new to this that is why

Comment: "I'm new to this" Then definitively do not buy anything. Start by renting some server in any provider, try to use it, see how it fits your load, then either invest in another one or just get more servers. It is not good practice to mix on the same server external services (website hosting) and internal ones (NAS, Inventory). This should be split anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A 4 core server would likely be overkill, do any of your proposed systems except the NAS will be OK - actually way overspecced if you don't have massively complex web hosting and inventory tracking needs.A NAS could be OK depending on your non-nss requirements.

For RAID, I'd actually recommend SOFTWARE raid 1 (mdadm) for Linux. If you require more then you can get with RAID1, go with RAID10 (or use LVM to do the same).  RAID5 is all but dead, and RAID6 requires expensive controllers to perform... and if something goes wrong, Software RAID1 is the easiest to recover.

If the primary purpose is as a NAS, you might want to buy a NAS rather then roll your own. You will get a lot less CPU, but easier management. Very often NAS's use Linux as the backend with a user friendly GUI.

Comment: How about ram? is 16gb enough

Comment: Why the down vote? Yes, 17 gigs of RAM would be more then you need unless you use ZFS.  You talk about ECC RAM - ECC ram is a good idea (but not mandatory), however its not normally useable in Intel desktop motherboards, so double check this. I would rather get a slower Xeon server board with ECC ram then an i7 without it for this purpose.  Also, you may want to factor the electricity costs of ryzen/older Intel systems as they can outweigh the savings.

Comment: I didn't the public did it

Comment: Hmm consider wise. Thanks.